# Как определить угол поворота изображения

Tags: c#

Есть картинка, которую необходимо повернуть так, чтобы стороны были параллельны осям.
Как определить угол, на который необходимо выполнить поворот?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На киберфоруме был похожий вопрос, и было предложено следующее решение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var angle = Math.Atan((float)(points[3].Y - points[0].Y) / (points[3].X - points[0].X)) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

, где
`points[0]` - левый верхний угол
`points[3]` - левый нижний угол

Но почему-то он повернул неправильно. Вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Игрек с иксом поменяйте, и, может, минус ещё нужен будет. На данный момент вы считаете угол между левой стороной и горизонталью, а нужно с вертикалью. В общем случае atan2 лучше применять